# Query in jq with args

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a problem with the JQ query results. The original json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "read": false,
    "mex": "message 1",
    "id": 1000
  },
  {
    "read": false,
    "mex": "message 2",
    "id": 2000
  },
  {
    "read": false,
    "mex": "message 3",
    "id": 3000
  }
```

]

I would like a query that would give me the results of the record that has the id 2000 (for example), these to be exact:

```
{
   "read": false,
   "mex": "message 2",
   "id": 2000
 }
```

With the following query outputs a blank record ("[ ]")

```
jq "map(select(.read==false))" file.json| jq -r 'map(select(.id==$foo))' --arg foo 2000
```

Answer (score 2):

The types don't match which is why it's not selecting.  The `id` fields are all numbers but you're comparing to a string.  `--arg` reads the parameter as a string.  You'll want to treat it as a number or the id as a string.  It'll just be easier to read the parameter as json using `--argjson`:

```
$ jq -r --argjson id 2000 'map(select((.read | not) and .id == $id))' file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple filter to select the object with .id 2000.

```
  .[]
| if .id == 2000 then . else empty end
```